# .NET MAUI CollectionView inside a Grid not shown correct on iPhone/iPad

Tags: .net, iphone, ipad, maui, collectionview

The MainPage of a simple .Net MAUI App contains a Grid with 4 Rows, all with the same height (*). They contain: Label, CollectionView, Button, Label
On Windows and Android the page is shown correct.
But on iPhone/iPad the CollectionView is much too high. It covers the Button and Label below (or it pushes them outside the screen)

When using a fix value for *Grid.Row=1* the issue does not happen

Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.6.1
.Net 7.0

Reproduce:

1. Create a .NET MAUI App
2. replace the XAML code in MainPage, the CollectionView has LightBlue background
3. run on Android emulator
4. run on iOS simulator

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*">
    <Label Margin="10" FontSize="30" Text="Header" />
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">

    </CollectionView>
    <Button
        Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" BackgroundColor="Grey"
        FontSize="40" Text="Button" />
    <Label
        Grid.Row="3" Margin="10" BackgroundColor="Coral"
        FontSize="40" Text="Footer" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Android vs iPhone]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue reported at GitHub - [Make CollectionView on iOS measure to content size #14951](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/14951) and [[iOS] Application stucks on iOS with combination of ScrollView, StackLayout, Editor and CollectionView #14955](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14955), please follow the progress at GitHub.

As descripted in the first merged thread, to fix the issue, PG team need modify the `CollectionView` on **iOS** to use its `ContentSize` as the value for `GetDesiredSize`; this forces the `CollectionView` to size to its content rather than attempting to fill the whole screen. So we may need for the next release of .net to get it fixed.

You can also try to use [the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-install) to upgrade to .NET 8 as an alternative workaround. For more information, you can refer to [Announcing a new version of the .NET Upgrade Assistant with support for .NET MAUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-general-availability/).

Comment: THX Alexandar May for the link to Upgrade Assistant, I gonna try!

Comment: @Haimo Thanks for the response! Or you can revert your Visual Studio 2022 to the version `17.5.5`. I've tested it and it worked well.

Comment: thanks, but I implemented an own workaround. For the next release I'll try C#8

Comment: @Haimo, can you share your work around, just starting target iOS and was stunned to find MAUI essentially unusable.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I just went to all the effort of uninstalling and reinstalling 17.5.5.  I do now have old visual studio but my workloads were not removed and reinstalled, they are all still stuck at 7.0.86.

Comment: Here is my work around for CollectionView issue at iOS:
- CollectionView sits inside a Grid
- Add methode to calculate height of the grid row in code behind and call it from constructor

    /// <summary>
/// mainGrid: Grid inside the page
/// collViewRow: Grid.Row of CollectionView
/// </summary>
private void CalculateSize()
{
 double all = 0; // height of rows in mainGrid
 foreach (RowDefinition row in mainGrid.RowDefinitions)
 {
  all += row.Height.Value;
 }
 double diff = this.Size.Height - all;
 // set height
 collViewRow.Height = collViewRow.Height.Value + diff;
}

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Just one more comment for everyone out there I installed the latest preview build of VS (preview 5.23393.2) and used the upgrade assistant.   The assistant is pretty neat but it left me with a project that would build but the platform targets were messed up, I then also had preview workloads installed.  In the end I had to uninstall just to get back to the current release workloads. I would not recommend attempting this, this was a huge time sink to find yet more unstable buggy MAUI.